# MATLAB writing text file "invalid permission" in UBUNTU

Tags: matlab, ubuntu-16.04, fopen

I'm trying to use MATLAB to write a text file in a folder other than "current folder" in UBUNTU. This folder is located in home directory so there would be no permission problem. I'm using the code that is shown below:

```
folder = '~/newFolder';
s1=fopen(folder,'newText.txt','w');
fprintf(s1,'hi')
fclose(s1);
```

But when I run the program, it shows `invalid permission` error. It would worth to mention that I've no problem when I try to write the text in the current folder. I also tried `chmod 0777 -R ~/newFolder` to modify the permission with no success.
What shall I do?

Thanks

Comment: The answer to this question is here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/401609-matlab-writing-text-file-invalid-permission-in-ubuntu?s_tid=mlc_ans_email_view#answer_320999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at to the `fopen` in [Matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html), you see that the second input argument in `permission` (that is related to the own function NOT your OS):

```
fileID = fopen(filename)
fileID = fopen(filename,permission)
```

But you are passing the filename as a second parameters.
you need to concatenate filepath and filename :

`s1=fopen(strcat(folder, 'newText.txt'),'w');`